# Countable additivity of outer measure with disjoint open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I'm curious if this is a valid argument. It makes sense to me, but I doubt my abilities with induction etc. Also, I'm not sure if I am making a jump from the definition of a measurable set, or if it is a sound progression.

The set-up Given a countable set of disjoint open intervals, $I_k$, prove the outer measure of their union equals the sum of their lengths, ie: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) =  |\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k|$

Thanks

We know that the outer measure of an open interval is just its length, that is $$|(a,b)|=(b-a)$$ We know that a set $E$ is measurable if for each set A, $$|A|=|A\cap E|+|A\cap E^c|\hspace{.5cm}(1)$$

We can use this to show equality with an induction argument.

For $k=1,|(I_1)|=l(I_1)$
as our open interval $I_1$ is measurable. Assume that $$|\cup_{k=1}^{N-1} I_k|=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} l(I_k)$$

Now take (1) with $A=I_1\cup \dots \cup I_N$ and $E=I_N$ Since $I_N$ is an interval, it is measurable and $$ |\cup_{k=1}^{N} I_k|= |(\cup_{k=1}^{N} I_k)\cap I_N| + (|\cup_{k=1}^{N} I_k\cap I_N^c|=|I_N|+|\cup_{k=1}^{N-1} I_k|$$

Now $|I_N|+|\cup_{k=1}^{N-1} I_k|$ is the sum we are looking for and as $$|\cup_{k=1}^{N} I_k|\subset |\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k|$$ we have that
$$|\cup_{k=1}^{N} I_k|\le |\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k|$$ for any positive $N$ by Axler 2.5 (outer measure preserves order), then
by our hypothesis$$|\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k|\ge |\cup_{k=1}^{N} I_k|\ge |\sum_{k=1}^{N} l(I_k)|$$  for any positive $N$. Take $N \rightarrow \infty$ to get $$|\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k|\ge |\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k)|$$ Now the other direction comes from the countable subadditivty of outer measure and we have $$|\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k|= |\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k)|$$ as desired

Comment: I don't see where $|\cup_{k=1}^{n+1} I_k|=|(I_{k+1})|+|(\cup_{k=1}^{n} I_k)|$ comes from...

Comment: From the line above (def of a measurable set), if we take those intersections, isn't that where we end up?

Comment: No. $I_k\cap I_{k+1}=\emptyset$ and $I_k\cap I_{k+1}^c=I_k$, so the previous line just says $|\bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k|=|\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k|$.

Comment: (more or less; there are also problems with indices that I see I inadvertently propagated.)

Comment: ok, thx. I am just struggling in general with my understanding

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich will u take a look at my edit? Thanks

Comment: Much better. yippee...

Comment: The result to be proved here is Exercise 11 in Section 2A of my book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis (legally available for free at http://measure.axler.net/). At this stage of the book, we do not yet know that outer measure is a measure on the Borel sets (if we did know that, then the exercise would be trivial because measures are countably additive). Thus the statement about measurable sets in the question is leading in the wrong direction. The result can be proved without measures, just using standard results developed in the book about outer measure.